# updating the weights for a perceptron step by step produces different result, why is that?

Tags: python, deep-learning, perceptron

A [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263027) gives an approach to find the (almost) best learning rate and initial weights so that a perceptron converges with the minimal iteration.

I modified the data a little bit,

```
nearest_setosa = np.array([[1.9, 0.4],[1.6, 0.6]])
```

and the best result over 2 iterations I got is

eat = 0.2, initial weights = [0.7, 0.7], trained weights = [-0.,  0.5]

which managed to separate the data points.

However, when I tried to reproduce the training step by step, I got a different set of trained weights [-0.06,  0.54]

Here are the steps

this initialize the params

```
model_w = np.asarray([0.7, 0.7])
model_b = 0.0
eta = .2
```

this code finds the wrongly separated examples, the same way as the original approach

```
for i in range(3):
    print(y_train[i] == predict(x_train[i]))
```

and then I got

```
False
False
True
```

so, I updated the weights regarding the first example, again, the same way as the original approach

```
update_weights(0, True)
```

new weights were

```
-0.2
[0.32 0.62]
```

and then I did the prediction again

```
for i in range(3):
    print(y_train[i] == predict(x_train[i]))
```

and got

```
False
False
True
```

and then again, I updated the weights

```
update_weights(0, True)
```

new weights were

```
-0.4
[-0.06  0.54]
```

which were different from the one from the original code.

What am I missing?

Comment: why is there a "deep-learning" tag here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed something in the code you posted.
You are only updating weights according to the data first data `id=0`.
If you look more closely at the code there is a loop:

```py
for i in range(3):
    if y_train[i] != predict(x_train[i],model_w, model_b):
        update_weights(i,model_w, model_b, eta)
    else:
        indicator+=1
```

In your case you have to do two updates `update_weights(0, True)` and `update_weights(1, True)` according to the `False` that you obtained.
Then you should update your weights according to the errors.

Comment: Thank you. I guess what I need is jus one update `update_weights(0)` and one `update_weights(1)`